# Automatically delete certain channel entries

Tags: channel, custom-fields, delete

My website has two channels: **pet_owners** and **pets**. **pets** channel also has custom field named **owner_id**.

My problem is: whenever an entry from **pet_owners** is deleted, would it be possible to force certain entries from **pets** to be deleted as well?

For example: if an entry from **pet_owner** gets deleted and its **entry_id** was ***55*** then how to automatically delete those **pet** channel entries where the value of **owner_id** would also be ***55***?

How to make it happen? Some plugin or module perhaps?

Thank you.

(P.S. The version of my EE is 2.5.5. Don't know if this information is important or not.)

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using actual relationships for this data? You'd still need a custom implementation to automatically delete children when a parent is deleted, but it seems like it would be easier to work with, more future proof, and also more powerful in terms of what you can do with the data on the front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search around didn't find any current third party modules to do this. What you're asking for would require a very small extension to be written, it would take well under an hour for a developer who knows EE. You'd just need an extension hooked to the

```
delete_entries_loop($val, $channel_id)
```

extension hook and use something like this:

```
function delete_pets($val, $channel_id)
{
    // look up field id
    $field_num = ee()->db->select('field_id')
                         ->where('field_name', 'owner_id')
                         ->get()
                         ->row_array();

    $field_id = 'field_id_' . $field_num['field_id'];

    // look up your entries with that field matching this entry
    $entry_ids = ee()->db->select('entry_id')
                         ->from('channel_data')
                         ->where($field_id, $val);
                         ->get()
                         ->result_array();

    // forgot to map this baby down
    $ids = array_map(function($a) { return $a['entry_id']; }, $entry_ids);

    // kill those entries
    ee()->api_channel_entries->delete_entry($ids);
}
```

Comment: Your code sample has a typo, but otherwise it works. Thank you.